# How do I dynamically execute function pointers having arbitrary argument types?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I have a several functions with varying types of arguments:

```
static void fn1(int* x, int* y);
static void fn2(int* x, int* y, int* z);
static void fn3(char* x, double y);
...
```

I'd like to create a new function that takes in a collection of function pointers, a collection of argument values, and executes each function in the collection, in sequence, with the correct argument values:

```
static void executeAlgorithm(
    vector<FN_PTR_TYPE> functionToExecute,
    map<FN_PTR_TYPE, FN_ARG_COLLECTION> args)
{
    // for each function in 'functionToExecute',
    // get the appropriate arguments, and call the
    // function using those arguments
}
```

What's the cleanest way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: The short answer is variadic templates and tuples. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Get rid of the map and make the vector a `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`; the arguments then just to into the function wrapper.

Comment: Use a language with less strict typing.

Comment: You could use a `std::variant<void(*)(int*, int*), ...>` but I don't think that would end up being clean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quite simple solution based on what @KerrekSB suggested in the comment. You basically `std::bind` a function and its args, and since you don't have to pass args any more your function becomes uniform `std::function<void()>` which is easy to store in a container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

static void fn1(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}

static void fn2(int x, int *y, double z)
{
    std::cout << x << " " << *y << " " << z << std::endl;
}

static void fn3(const char* x, bool y)
{
    std::cout << x << " " << std::boolalpha << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> binds;
    int i = 20;

    binds.push_back(std::bind(&fn1, 1, 2));
    binds.push_back(std::bind(&fn1, 3, 4));
    binds.push_back(std::bind(&fn2, 1, &i, 3.99999));
    binds.push_back(std::bind(&fn2, 3, &i, 0.8971233921));
    binds.push_back(std::bind(&fn3, "test1", true));
    binds.push_back(std::bind(&fn3, "test2", false));

    for (auto fn : binds) fn();
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/JtCPsj

```
1 2
3 4
1 20 3.99999
3 20 0.897123
test1 true
test2 false
```

Comment: Great. This is what I want. Ideally, I wouldn't have a dependency on C++11, but it's not that big of a deal.

Comment: Thanks to you, and also to @KerrekSB for the great tip!

Comment: @Kirby: No problem, I'm glad someone else expanded it :-)

Comment: @Kirby: There's nothing in principle that stops you from implementing something *like* `std::function` in C++98. The main thing you'd miss would be the variadic `bind`, which you could replace with a more targeted special solution for your use case. In particular, you do *not* need a variadic specialization of `std::function<T>`, since you only ever need the case `T = void()`.